# Round to float by money

Tags: python, python-3.x, rounding

I'm not the best programmer but I'm making a money counting program. I'm trying to get my program to round a float to two decimal places without making this happen when you run it:

```
How many $100 do you have
0
How many $50 do you have
0
How many $20 do you have
4
How many $10 do you have
1
How many $5 do you have
14
How many $2 do you have
1
How many $1 do you have
4
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004444444444
444444444411111111111414141414114
```

P.s. I'm not doing cent parts yet

P.s.s The round function dosent work as well
as I thought it would

Here's my coding:

```
#Bill Parts
print "How many $100 do you have"
hundred_bill = raw_input('')
hundred_billone = hundred_bill * 100
#======================================================================
print "How many $50 do you have"
fifty_bill = raw_input('')
fifty_billone = fifty_bill * 50
#======================================================================
print "How many $20 do you have"
twenty_bill = raw_input('')
twenty_billone = twenty_bill * 20
#======================================================================
print "How many $10 do you have"
ten_bill = raw_input('')
ten_billone = ten_bill * 10
#======================================================================
print "How many $5 do you have"
five_bill = raw_input('')
five_billone = five_bill * 5
#======================================================================
print "How many $2 do you have"
two_bill = raw_input('')
two_billone = two_bill * 2
#======================================================================
print "How many $1 do you have"
one_bill = raw_input('')
one_billone = one_bill * 1
#======================================================================
#======================================================================
#======================================================================
#Cent Parts








#======================================================================
bills = hundred_billone + fifty_billone + twenty_billone + ten_billone +                 
five_billone + two_billone + one_billone
print bills
```

Comment: You should combine `print` and `raw_input` for cleaner code. Also, you need to typecast your result from `str` to `float`.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with rounding; what you're seeing is the fact that multiplication of strings by x in Python repeats the string x times. For example when you input `"14"` and then do `five_bill * 5` you get "1414141414".

Comment: Money is not a floating point commodity, it's fixed point (ie there's no such thing, physically, as 0.275 of a cent). Do your calculations in integers (cents) and then divide and mod by 100 to give dollars and cents.
There was a trap back in the 8 bit days where the floating point value didn't accurately represent the fixed point value.

Answer (score 2):

In python 2 and 3 you can .quantize() a Decimal to any precision you want:

```
Decimal('7.325').quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)
Decimal('7.32')

Decimal('7.325').quantize(Decimal('1.'), rounding=ROUND_UP)
Decimal('8')
```

For more info check https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html